# How to display all the values of the categorical variable using Plotly Choropleth

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization

The task is to display the state wise category when mouse is hovered over the state, but it is displaying only the last option for all the states which is vegetables.

Here is the code which I have tried.

```
fig = px.choropleth(data, 
                    locations="id", 
                    geojson=state,
                    color="Category",
                    hover_name="State",
                    scope="usa",
                    hover_data = ["Year", "Dollars"]
                    )

fig.show()
```

The result which I am getting now.

[image]

How can I display all the values which are there in Category variable?

Dataset Link: https://github.com/satyam2829/Choropleth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- your data does not seem very suitable for what you are trying to achieve. Have de-duped and summarised

  - created *ColumnList* all categories in state
  - created *Categories* count of categories in state
- modified **plotly express** `choropleth()` to use this summarised data
- to make colors would correctly,  it's normally the case you need to defined **featureidkey** to link dataframe column to appropriate property in GeoJSON

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

state = requests.get(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/satyam2829/Choropleth/main/us-states.json"
).json()
data = pd.read_csv(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/satyam2829/Choropleth/main/WeeklyFoodPrices.csv"
)
data["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(data["Date"])


# 1. de-dup data,  take just last date for each state
# 2. summarise data for state as each state has many categories
data = (
    data.merge(
        data.groupby("State", as_index=False).agg({"Date": "max"}),
        on=["State", "Date"],
        how="inner",
    )
    .groupby(["State", "Date"], as_index=False)
    .agg(
        Category=("Category", "last"),
        Dollars=("Dollars", "last"),
        LastYear=("LastYear", "last"),
        CategoryList=("Category", list),
        Categories=("Category","size")
    )
)

fig = px.choropleth(
    data,
    locations="State",
    featureidkey="properties.name",  # needed as this is the common property
    geojson=state,
    color="Category",
    hover_name="State",
    scope="usa",
    hover_data=["LastYear", "Dollars", "Categories", "CategoryList"],
)

fig
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I have tried this, but it is not working for me. However, I have added the link of dataset and geojson file.

Comment: have modified answer to use data and geojson that you provided.  data really doesn't make a good choropleth as last category is always *Vegtables*.  anyway now have list of all categories which is your question

Comment: This is working. If in case, I need to show total yearly sales category wise, what needs to be done?

Comment: simple case of changing **pandas** named aggregation from `LastYear=("LastYear", "last"),` to `LastYear=("LastYear", list),`